# Cannot use typescript class from other local typescript module using browserify

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, browserify, tsify

I have a common npm module containing TypeScript which is an node module providing some classes and functionality. This module is packaged via `browserify` + `tsify` and also exports the declaration files and built with gulp.

I have another npm module using TypeScript which imports this module locally via `file:../modulename` and tries to use functionality from the first module. The second module is also packaged via `browserify` + `tsify` and built with `gulp`. The compilation of the second module works via `npx tsc`, but fails if I execute the gulp build file with the error message

```
Error: Cannot find module './AbstractClass' from 'folderInOtherModuleContainingTheJSFiles'
```

Interestingly it sometimes fails with this Class sometimes with another, so it seems there is also some kind of concurrent processing.

I extracted the failing code from my project and created a minimal example with this behavior [here](https://github.com/Sheldan/npm-minimal-working-example).

`npm version: 5.6.0
node version: v9.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who might come to this post and face the same error.

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/tsify/issues/235) at tsify too, thinking it has something to do with the plugin, because `npx tsc` worked.

Luckily the issue has been resolved, although with a workaround. There seems to be a name collision which causes `browserify` to think that a `require` call, which is a variable, in the resulting bundle needs to be resolved, but can't. The workaround is uglifying the resulting bundle, so that the conflict does not happen. More details in the above linked issue.